# What's the best possible score on the credits mini game?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

In the credits minigame you get a point for every name you hit and lose points whenever an enemy hits you. Since there's only a limited number of names to hit, what's the best possible score you can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 435, according to this video:

But doing a perfect score, sadly, doesn't unlock any secret ending scene.